# Can I add a page without clearing cache?

Tags: routes, hooks, 7, uri

I have written a module by which user can add custom pages. Do I need to clear the cache every time user adds a page? Is there a way to adding pages without clearing cache? If yes what is it? and if no what's the function I should call?

Is `hook_menu` the only function I should put my code in it?

Does the Views module clear cache after submitting a new page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clearing the cache you should do, it's `menu_rebuild();` if you change router items.